# How to make rtmpdump accept an url taken from a file // setlocal's and endlocal's effects on batch variables -

Tags: batch-file, rtmp

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
wget --output-document=Content.xml Link
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('find "1280x720" Content.xml') do set found=%%a

set Url=!found:~5,-6!
for /f "delims=" %%a in (""!Url!"") do endlocal & set "Url=%%~a"
set Filename=Whatever.mp4

:start
rtmpdump -r %Url% -e -b 60000000 -o C:\Users\User\Desktop\%Filename%

if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto start
if exist Content.xml del Content.xml
```

[wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) does its job correctly.

The relevant line is correctly stored in the Url variable.

[rtmpdump](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) doesn't work.

Id est, instead of displaying the mp4's data (as INFO:) and starting to download, it says "Starting download at 0.000kB" (expected) and stays there until timeout (not expected). After a while an "ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header" happens. Then, as per the :start loop, it does the same again and again (or until stopped).

```
@echo off

set Url=rtmpe://Stuff.mp4

set Filename=Whatever.mp4

:start
rtmpdump -r %Url% -e -b 60000000 -o C:\Users\User\Desktop\%Filename%

if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto start
```

This (manually inputing the rtmpe line, after reading it from the Content.xml file) works.

Link, User, Stuff and Whatever are obviously placeholders for data that I believe to be irrelevant for the problem at hand.

Worth of notice: setting Url manually in the first file still leads to an error, unless it's done *after* the endlocal statement.

I believe the issue may lay in how "local" variables are stored, but I have no notion of that.

So, can anyone explain what's going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any reason for using delayed environment variable expansion in your batch file for this task.

```
@echo off
wget.exe --output-document=Content.xml Link
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "1280x720" Content.xml') do set found=%%a

set "Url=%found:~5,-6%"
set "Filename=Whatever.mp4"
set "LoopCount=0"

:Loop
rtmpdump.exe -r %Url% -e -b 60000000 -o "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%Filename%"
if not errorlevel 2 goto EndBatch
set /A "LoopCount+=1"
if not "%LoopCount%"=="3" goto Loop

:EndBatch
if exist Content.xml del Content.xml
```

Comment: Ok, this works. I had added delayed expansion because the _set Url=%found:~5,-6%_ line wasn't working for me and I hadn't thought of trying quotation marks as a fix.

Would be interesting to know how to make this work if delayed expansion _was_ necessary, but I'll accept this answer as correct, since it solves my issue.

Thanks.